# Control ArduinoUNO board from Android phone via USB connection

Tags: python, android, usb, arduino-uno, chaquopy

I'm create the Application for python files should run in Android phone.
I'm using in Chaquopy pacakages which support for python files is run in Java Skeleton code in Android Studio. After the build APK files, installed in Android phone and **Connect the ArduinoUNO board to phone via USB Connection**.

Here, my problem is " when I'm Calling the Python file using java code,and to send message signal passing to ArduinoUNO. When ArduinoUNO is Blink the LED ON/OFF"? If it is possible?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.felhr.serialportexample;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Set;

import com.chaquo.python.PyObject;
import com.chaquo.python.Python;
import com.chaquo.python.android.AndroidPlatform;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView output;
    EditText CodeArea;
    Button Run;

    /*
     * Notifications from UsbService will be received here.
     */
    private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            switch (intent.getAction()) {
                case UsbService.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED: // USB PERMISSION GRANTED
                    Toast.makeText(context, "USB Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case UsbService.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED: // USB PERMISSION NOT GRANTED
                    Toast.makeText(context, "USB Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case UsbService.ACTION_NO_USB: // NO USB CONNECTED
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No USB connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case UsbService.ACTION_USB_DISCONNECTED: // USB DISCONNECTED
                    Toast.makeText(context, "USB disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case UsbService.ACTION_USB_NOT_SUPPORTED: // USB NOT SUPPORTED
                    Toast.makeText(context, "USB device not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    private UsbService usbService;
    private TextView display;
    private EditText editText;
    private MyHandler mHandler;
    private final ServiceConnection usbConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1) {
            usbService = ((UsbService.UsbBinder) arg1).getService();
            usbService.setHandler(mHandler);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            usbService = null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mHandler = new MyHandler(this);

        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        CodeArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codearea);
        Run = (Button) findViewById(R.id.run);
        if(!Python.isStarted())
            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));

        Run.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Python py = Python.getInstance();
                PyObject pyobj = py.getModule("myscript"); // here we will give name of our python file

                PyObject obj = pyobj.callAttr("main",CodeArea.getText().toString());
                if (!CodeArea.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    String data = CodeArea.getText().toString();
                if (usbService != null) { // if UsbService was correctly binded, Send data
                    usbService.write(data.getBytes());
                    output.setText(obj.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setFilters();  // Start listening notifications from UsbService
        startService(UsbService.class, usbConnection, null); // Start UsbService(if it was not started before) and Bind it
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver);
        unbindService(usbConnection);
    }

    private void startService(Class<?> service, ServiceConnection serviceConnection, Bundle extras) {
        if (!UsbService.SERVICE_CONNECTED) {
            Intent startService = new Intent(this, service);
            if (extras != null && !extras.isEmpty()) {
                Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
                for (String key : keys) {
                    String extra = extras.getString(key);
                    startService.putExtra(key, extra);
                }
            }
            startService(startService);
        }
        Intent bindingIntent = new Intent(this, service);
        bindService(bindingIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    private void setFilters() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(UsbService.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        filter.addAction(UsbService.ACTION_NO_USB);
        filter.addAction(UsbService.ACTION_USB_DISCONNECTED);
        filter.addAction(UsbService.ACTION_USB_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        filter.addAction(UsbService.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED);
        registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
    }

    /*
     * This handler will be passed to UsbService. Data received from serial port is displayed through this handler
     */
    private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<MainActivity> mActivity;

        public MyHandler(MainActivity activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case UsbService.MESSAGE_FROM_SERIAL_PORT:
                    String data = (String) msg.obj;
                    mActivity.get().display.append(data);
                    break;
                case UsbService.CTS_CHANGE:
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity.get(), "CTS_CHANGE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case UsbService.DSR_CHANGE:
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity.get(), "DSR_CHANGE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**USBservice.java**

```
package com.felhr.serialportexample;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import com.felhr.usbserial.CDCSerialDevice;
import com.felhr.usbserial.UsbSerialDevice;
import com.felhr.usbserial.UsbSerialInterface;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class UsbService extends Service {

    public static final String TAG = "UsbService";

    public static final String ACTION_USB_READY = "com.felhr.connectivityservices.USB_READY";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_ATTACHED = "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_DETACHED = "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_NOT_SUPPORTED = "com.felhr.usbservice.USB_NOT_SUPPORTED";
    public static final String ACTION_NO_USB = "com.felhr.usbservice.NO_USB";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED = "com.felhr.usbservice.USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED = "com.felhr.usbservice.USB_PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_DISCONNECTED = "com.felhr.usbservice.USB_DISCONNECTED";
    public static final String ACTION_CDC_DRIVER_NOT_WORKING = "com.felhr.connectivityservices.ACTION_CDC_DRIVER_NOT_WORKING";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_DEVICE_NOT_WORKING = "com.felhr.connectivityservices.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_NOT_WORKING";
    public static final int MESSAGE_FROM_SERIAL_PORT = 0;
    public static final int CTS_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int DSR_CHANGE = 2;
    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
    private static final int BAUD_RATE = 9600; // BaudRate. Change this value if you need
    public static boolean SERVICE_CONNECTED = false;

    private IBinder binder = new UsbBinder();

    private Context context;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private UsbManager usbManager;
    private UsbDevice device;
    private UsbDeviceConnection connection;
    private UsbSerialDevice serialPort;

    private boolean serialPortConnected;
    /*
     *  Data received from serial port will be received here. Just populate onReceivedData with your code
     *  In this particular example. byte stream is converted to String and send to UI thread to
     *  be treated there.
     */
    private UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
            try {
                String data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");
                if (mHandler != null)
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_FROM_SERIAL_PORT, data).sendToTarget();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    /*
     * State changes in the CTS line will be received here
     */
    private UsbSerialInterface.UsbCTSCallback ctsCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbCTSCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCTSChanged(boolean state) {
            if(mHandler != null)
                mHandler.obtainMessage(CTS_CHANGE).sendToTarget();
        }
    };

    /*
     * State changes in the DSR line will be received here
     */
    private UsbSerialInterface.UsbDSRCallback dsrCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbDSRCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onDSRChanged(boolean state) {
            if(mHandler != null)
                mHandler.obtainMessage(DSR_CHANGE).sendToTarget();
        }
    };
    /*
     * Different notifications from OS will be received here (USB attached, detached, permission responses...)
     * About BroadcastReceiver: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html
     */
    private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            if (arg1.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)) {
                boolean granted = arg1.getExtras().getBoolean(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                if (granted) // User accepted our USB connection. Try to open the device as a serial port
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                    arg0.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
                    new ConnectionThread().start();
                } else // User not accepted our USB connection. Send an Intent to the Main Activity
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED);
                    arg0.sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            } else if (arg1.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_ATTACHED)) {
                if (!serialPortConnected)
                    findSerialPortDevice(); // A USB device has been attached. Try to open it as a Serial port
            } else if (arg1.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_DETACHED)) {
                // Usb device was disconnected. send an intent to the Main Activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_DISCONNECTED);
                arg0.sendBroadcast(intent);
                if (serialPortConnected) {
                    serialPort.close();
                }
                serialPortConnected = false;
            }
        }
    };

    /*
     * onCreate will be executed when service is started. It configures an IntentFilter to listen for
     * incoming Intents (USB ATTACHED, USB DETACHED...) and it tries to open a serial port.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.context = this;
        serialPortConnected = false;
        UsbService.SERVICE_CONNECTED = true;
        setFilter();
        usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        findSerialPortDevice();
    }

    /* MUST READ about services
     * http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
     * http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        serialPort.close();
        unregisterReceiver(usbReceiver);
        UsbService.SERVICE_CONNECTED = false;
    }

    /*
     * This function will be called from MainActivity to write data through Serial Port
     */
    public void write(byte[] data) {
        if (serialPort != null)
            serialPort.write(data);
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler mHandler) {
        this.mHandler = mHandler;
    }

    private void findSerialPortDevice() {
        // This snippet will try to open the first encountered usb device connected, excluding usb root hubs
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usbDevices = usbManager.getDeviceList();
        if (!usbDevices.isEmpty()) {

            // first, dump the hashmap for diagnostic purposes
            for (Map.Entry<String, UsbDevice> entry : usbDevices.entrySet()) {
                device = entry.getValue();
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("USBDevice.HashMap (vid:pid) (%X:%X)-%b class:%X:%X name:%s",
                        device.getVendorId(), device.getProductId(),
                        UsbSerialDevice.isSupported(device),
                        device.getDeviceClass(), device.getDeviceSubclass(),
                        device.getDeviceName()));
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, UsbDevice> entry : usbDevices.entrySet()) {
                device = entry.getValue();
                int deviceVID = device.getVendorId();
                int devicePID = device.getProductId();

//                if (deviceVID != 0x1d6b && (devicePID != 0x0001 && devicePID != 0x0002 && devicePID != 0x0003) && deviceVID != 0x5c6 && devicePID != 0x904c) {
                if (UsbSerialDevice.isSupported(device)) {
                    // There is a supported device connected - request permission to access it.
                    requestUserPermission();
                    break;
                } else {
                    connection = null;
                    device = null;
                }
            }
            if (device==null) {
                // There are no USB devices connected (but usb host were listed). Send an intent to MainActivity.
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_NO_USB);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "findSerialPortDevice() usbManager returned empty device list." );
            // There is no USB devices connected. Send an intent to MainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_NO_USB);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    private void setFilter() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_DETACHED);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_ATTACHED);
        registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter);
    }

    /*
     * Request user permission. The response will be received in the BroadcastReceiver
     */
    private void requestUserPermission() {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("requestUserPermission(%X:%X)", device.getVendorId(), device.getProductId() ) );
        PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        usbManager.requestPermission(device, mPendingIntent);
    }

    public class UsbBinder extends Binder {
        public UsbService getService() {
            return UsbService.this;
        }
    }

    /*
     * A simple thread to open a serial port.
     * Although it should be a fast operation. moving usb operations away from UI thread is a good thing.
     */
    private class ConnectionThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            serialPort = UsbSerialDevice.createUsbSerialDevice(device, connection);
            if (serialPort != null) {
                if (serialPort.open()) {
                    serialPortConnected = true;
                    serialPort.setBaudRate(BAUD_RATE);
                    serialPort.setDataBits(UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8);
                    serialPort.setStopBits(UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1);
                    serialPort.setParity(UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE);
                    /**
                     * Current flow control Options:
                     * UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF
                     * UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_RTS_CTS only for CP2102 and FT232
                     * UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_DSR_DTR only for CP2102 and FT232
                     */
                    serialPort.setFlowControl(UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF);
                    serialPort.read(mCallback);
                    serialPort.getCTS(ctsCallback);
                    serialPort.getDSR(dsrCallback);

                    //
                    // Some Arduinos would need some sleep because firmware wait some time to know whether a new sketch is going
                    // to be uploaded or not
                    //Thread.sleep(2000); // sleep some. YMMV with different chips.

                    // Everything went as expected. Send an intent to MainActivity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_READY);
                    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                } else {
                    // Serial port could not be opened, maybe an I/O error or if CDC driver was chosen, it does not really fit
                    // Send an Intent to Main Activity
                    if (serialPort instanceof CDCSerialDevice) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_CDC_DRIVER_NOT_WORKING);
                        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_DEVICE_NOT_WORKING);
                        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // No driver for given device, even generic CDC driver could not be loaded
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_NOT_SUPPORTED);
                context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.felhr.serialportexample.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/head"
        android:text="PyCompile"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/codearea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/head"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="10"
        android:maxLines="1000"
        android:minLines="8"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/run"
        android:text="Run"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/codearea"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_below="@+id/run"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Android Studio is only the IDE which compiles the app. If you say "Running python files in android studio" this means you want to execute a Python script on your PC - which I assume is not what you want as you want to execute it inside your Android app on the Android phone. So your title is totally misleading. I would strongly recommend to rename it to something like "Running python files in an Android app".

Comment: @Robert It looks like the code is already calling running Python code on Android using Chaquopy. The actual question is about how to control an Arduino over USB from an Android device, and the solution to that won't necessarily involve Python, so I'll edit the title accordingly.